# HTML default class for css selector

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im working on a react project and I'm a bit confused as to how the `div` class selectors `'middle aligned content'` and `'large caret up icon'` are being interpreted as I don't have any of these defined in a css file. Are these default class css selectors? If so what are these selectors called so I can look up all of these default values. Thank you.

```
<div className='middle aligned content'>
  <div className='header'>
   <a>
    <i className='large caret up icon' />
   </a>
  {this.props.votes}
 </div>
</dv>
```

Comment: Hey! Are you using any CSS framework like Bootstrap or Material Design ?

Comment: ReactJS has no CSS by *default*. It's probable that you've combined it with a framework that contains some CSS, and the framework has predefined rules for those classes.

Comment: would SemanticUI be what it is? I import that in my index.html. Yeaaahhh thats it. Im bad, thanks guys :)

Comment: Note that those spaces denote multiple different classes. So your first div doesn't have a class of "middle aligned content" it has a class of "middle", "aligned", and "content". Remove the spaces to make it one class.